# Python: Remove any characters before the first letter

Tags: python, string

Hello I have a dataframe with a column that contains strings with area codes in front of some country names.

I would like to remove all characters before the first letter if present to get a column with only country names.

Eample:

```
1-United States
44-United Kingdom
Mauritius
61-Australia
Cambodia
Colombia
86-China
852-Hong Kong
Romania
46-Sweden
```

Desired output:

```
United States
United Kingdom
Mauritius
Australia
Cambodia
Colombia
China
Hong Kong
Romania
Sweden
```

Thanks in advance! I appreciate any input on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use regular expression for this task following way

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"name":["1-United States","44-United Kingdom","Mauritius"]})
df["clean_name"] = df["name"].str.replace(r"^[^A-Za-z]+", "", regex=True)
print(df)
```

output:

```
                name      clean_name
0    1-United States   United States
1  44-United Kingdom  United Kingdom
2          Mauritius       Mauritius
```

Explanation: regular expression is used to remove all (`+`) leading (1st `^`) characters, which are not (2nd `^`) ASCII letters (`A-Za-z`). Beware that this solution is limited to ASCII letters only.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda s: ''.join([i for i in s if i.isalpha()]))
```

To do it using regex:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace('[^a-zA-Z ]', '')
```